# converting a series to string in pandas, quirk

Tags: pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, series

I am trying to convert a series to a string,

When I convert, for some reason the whole text in the cell is not replicated, it is being cut off by ....

how can i convert it to a string with it showing the full text?

`summ1 = list1.iloc[bglist,0] #my list

bg_summ = bg_summ1.to_string(header=False,index=False) #converting list into string`

[the top is my series item, then i convert it into a string, the rest of the text gets cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7yIe.png)

Comment: @jezrael, my question is different, I know u are an expert, but please give some care to newbies like myself thanks :)

Comment: It is weird, do you try answers from dupe?

Comment: its annoying now because i cant repost another questions till 90mins later. (since u merged my answer) 

Im not trying to print an output, 
Im trying to convert a series to a string, for some reason its does not covert fully,
the individual items/strings in the series gets cut off with a .....

Comment: OK, so please change your question for possible test your problem, [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Then add suggestion from dupe for possible test if not working and then after testing it fail I reopen. Because I think it working nice.

Comment: But maybe  iam wrong, so please add some sample data for test. [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: bro, i have less than 10 post, im not allowed to post pictures, thats why it created that imgur link

Comment: Maybe [help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)